# Uppercase first letters in multi-level lists (JS, JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor4.x

I'm trying to do some custom Capitalization Tool for CKEditor, which is used by us. But even without CKEditor it seems to be an interesting case.

**For now I would like to have some good solution for selecting just LEVEL 1 elements and capitalize all included TEXT without touching sub-levels HTML  structure, and then capitalize LEVEL 2 without touching LEVEL1.
I've tried many excluding methods with many pointing combinations.
We can't use classes and id's.**

It seems that when we are using function for capitalize, STRINGS (contents texts) which we are getting back from it, when we are inserting them into code, are messing with HTML structure.

Current goal: do not destroy nested structure by joining them all and moving them to parent element.

**Current progress:**

- *We can capitalize only LEVEL 1 elements - but with side effect:
  joining sub-levels and adding them to LEVEL 1 parent element.*
- *We can capitalize only nested LEVEL 2 elements.*
- *We can capitalize both LEVEL 1 and LEVEL 2 elements together - but

  with side effect: joining sub-levels and adding them to LEVEL 1 parent
  element.*

I have some ideas, but maybe I need some fresh look at this problem.

**For now it seems to be the moment for important question:
Is there just need for more specific way for selecting elements, better way for replacing texts, or is it place for totally different and more complex approach?**

I've prepared a test environment with current version of code and example data - now is there active two functions to show operation on LEVEL 1 and LEVEL 2 elements:

https://codepen.io/adalbertus/pen/jxOGYV

HTML:

```
<p>FIRST LIST after header- we want it to change:</p>

<h2>Some header to target proper lists</h2>

<ul>
<li>text 1 - Level 1</li> 
<li>text 2 - Level 1
    <ul>
        <li>text 1 - Level 2</li> 
        <li>text 2 - Level 2</li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li>text 3 - Level 1</li>
<li>text 4 - Level 1</li>
```

```
<p>SECOND LIST after header - we don't want it to change:</p>
<ul>
<li>text 1 - Level 1</li> 
<li>text 2 - Level 1
    <ul>
        <li>text 1 - Level 2</li> 
        <li>text 2 - Level 2</li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li>text 3 - Level 1</li>
<li>text 4 - Level 1</li>
```

JS:

```
$("#capitalize").click(function (){

function capitalizeFirstLetter(lists){
return lists.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lists.slice(1);}

//Condition to target only lists directly after Headers is not necessary, but let say it will be there.
//So this is the reason to exist such variables like below - to easily change this in the future:
var h2Andh3TagsToTargetLiElements = $("body").find("h2,h3");
var listsToCapitalize = $("body").find("ul");
var listsAfterHeaders =     $(h2Andh3TagsToTargetLiElements).next(listsToCapitalize).find("li");
var nestedListsToCapitalize = $("body").find("ul > li > ul , ul > li > ol");
var nestedListsAfterHeaders =$(h2Andh3TagsToTargetLiElements).next(nestedListsToCapitalize).contents().find("li");


if (listsAfterHeaders.length) {

//Operation just for nested lists - just for tests
$(nestedListsAfterHeaders).each(function () {
var nested = $(this).text();
var nestedtocap = capitalizeFirstLetter(nested);
  $(this).text(nestedtocap);
                                          });
$(listsAfterHeaders).each(function () {
var totxt = $(this).text();
var tocap = capitalizeFirstLetter(totxt);
  $(this).text(tocap);
                                    });
                          }

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done much more simply, if I have understood your question correctly.

```
$("#capitalize").click(function() {
  function capitalizeFirstLetter(lists) {
    return lists.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + lists.slice(1);
  }

  $("body > ul > li").each(function(idx, el) {
      $(el).html($(el).html().charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $(el).html().slice(1));
  });
});
```

Basically, only select items that follow the `body > ul > li` hierarchy.

Comment: You could also use `body > h2 + ul > li` or similar if you did want to keep the "only after headers" restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if I am getting you correct but you are looking for some control over the nested elements. Here is a plain js solution without jquery or querySelectors that might help:

```
//assuming that we have an ul variable where li descendants always
have a text node as the first child:
    var ul = document.createElement("ul");
    ul.innerHTML = `<li>text 1 - Level 1</li> 
    <li>text 2 - Level 1
        <ul>
            <li>text 1 - Level 2</li> 
            <li>text 2 - Level 2</li> 
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>text 3 - Level 1</li>
    <li>text 4 - Level 1</li>`;


     /*create a function to capitalize the first letter,
    I'm using regex incase you want to do different manipulations other than
     capitalizing.Below, Node is a ul element, gets the immediate 
li elements and performs replace*/
             function capitalize(node){
                Array.prototype.slice.call(node.children)
                .filter(function(d,i){return d.tagName === "LI" })
                .forEach(function(d,i){
                    d.firstChild.textContent 
                    = d.firstChild.textContent
                        .replace(/^[A-Z]/gi,function(m,o,s){return m.toUpperCase();})})
            }
```

To get the 'levels', here is a function that returns an array containing ul nodes of that level:

```
function getLevels(level,parent){
    var nodes = [parent],
        children = undefined;
    for (var i = 0;i<level;++i){
        nodes = nodes.map(function(d,i){
            return d 
            && d.nodeType 
            && (children = Array.prototype.slice.call(d.children))
            .filter(function(d,i){return d.tagName === "UL"})
        }).reduce(function(ac,d,i){
            return ac.concat(d);
        },[])
        if(!nodes.length && i !== level - 1){
            nodes = children;
        }
    }
    return nodes;
}
```

So for example, for ul variable:

```
getLevels(0,ul);//return the parent itself [ul]
getLevels(1,ul);//return empty [] since all immediate children are li
getLevels(2,ul);//return [ul] containing ul inside the second li
```

Now, to capitalize the 2nd level ul's li tags:

```
getLevels(2,ul).forEach(function(d,i){capitalize(d)})
```

You end up with:

```
<li>text 1 - Level 1</li> 
<li>text 2 - Level 1
    <ul>
        <li>Text 1 - Level 2</li> 
        <li>Text 2 - Level 2</li> 
    </ul>
</li>
<li>text 3 - Level 1</li>
<li>text 4 - Level 1</li>
```

I wrote this adhoc & on the fly so the error checking in edge cases might need an edit or two.